# Expo publish to EAS update

Tags: react-native, go, expo, eas

I'm currently developing an app with expo and I'm used to share my app to my testers by expo go: they scan my qr code that allows them to access the default channel.

Usually I use `expo publish` but now I have `expo publish is not supported in the local CLI, please use eas update instead`, so I try to migrate to eas update, but it's way trickier than expected.

I have created a default channel with `eas channel` pointed my branch to it and did multiple `eas update` but my app doesn't update anymore. I tried to find if it was another qr code but I didn't find any that points directly to the branch, only the ones that point on a specific update.
I don't know if I should put something specific in the `app.json` or `eas.json`, everything I tried didn't work.

Is there a QR code for a eas branch? If not, is there a way to reproduce what `expo publish` did before?

I'm struggling with that since a few weeks now, if you have any answer it'd be a huge help!

Comment: see if it's helpful: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1753

Comment: Sadly I already tried but I have the same output (not supported in the local CLI)